# Bluemix SSL BXNUI0081E

Tags: ssl-certificate, ibm-cloud

Our platform services are growing and we need to support additional domains that are protected with SSL. We provision various applications via subdomains and have wildcard certs to protect most of our applications. Without the ability to add more soon this may keep us from staying with bluemix long term. Is there any workaround for multiple SSL? Can I do a different type of container/app or something to get aorund this and host the cert within the app rather than via bluemix? Is there any roadmap for allowing us to pay for more than 4 slots?

Comment: any update from your side? we are kind of stuck with the same issue

Comment: No way to do it on bluemix side of things. We had to consolodate our domains to 4 and rely on subdomains with wildcard ssl certs.